# IdentityServer4: Google sign-in only show OpenID scope and didn't show the email and profile scope information

Tags: identityserver4

When i'm trying to sign-in with google sign-in from blazor webassembly, the requested claims and the claims returned from identity server is not matching (see output)
**BackEnd/Config.cs**

```
namespace BackEnd
{
    public static class ServerConfiguration
    {
        public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources =>
            new IdentityResource[]
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile(),
                new IdentityResources.Email(),
                new IdentityResource("roles", "User roles", new List<string> { "role" })
            };
        public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
            new ApiScope[]
            {
                new ApiScope("protectedScope", "Protected Scope")
            };
        public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
            new Client[]
            {
                new Client()
                {
                    ClientId = <confidential>,
                    ClientName = "client 1",
                    RequireClientSecret = false,
                    RequirePkce = true,
                    AllowedCorsOrigins = { "https://localhost:5001" },
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                    RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5001/authentication/login-callback" },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5001/" },
                    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                    AllowedScopes = new List<string>{
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                        "protectedScope"
                    }
                },
                new Client()
                {
                    ClientId = "blazor",
                    ClientName = "oidcUser",
                    RequireClientSecret = false,
                    RequirePkce = true,
                    RequireConsent = true,
                    AllowedCorsOrigins = { "https://localhost:5001" },
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                    RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5001/authentication/login-callback" },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5001/" },
                    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
                    AllowedScopes = new List<string>{
                        "openid",
                        "email",
                        "profile",
                        "protectedScope"
                    }
                }
            };
        public static List<TestUser> TestUsers { 
            get
            {
                TestUser user1 = new TestUser()
                {
                    SubjectId = "2f47f8f0-bea1-4f0e-ade1-88533a0eaf57",
                    Username = "John",
                    Claims = new List<Claim>()
                    {
                        new Claim("role", "SignedInUser"),
                        new Claim("email", "johnsmith@gmail.com"),
                        new Claim("picture", "https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.business2community.com%2Fsocial-media%2Fimportance-profile-picture-career-01899604&psig=AOvVaw2LC5T-WZMYnHD9I7PeK7lT&ust=1615219065948000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=2ahUKEwip1caGxp7vAhV1NbcAHd_2BFwQjRx6BAgAEAc")
                    }
                };
                List<TestUser> testUsers = new List<TestUser>();
                testUsers.Add(user1);

                return testUsers;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**BackEnd/Startup.cs**

```
namespace BackEnd
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        private string _clientId = null;
        private string _clientSecret = null;

        public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment environment, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Environment = environment;
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            var cert = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(".", "IdsvCertificate.pfx"), "YouShallNotPass123");

            _clientId = Configuration["OAuth:ClientId"];
            _clientSecret = Configuration["OAuth:ClientSecret"];

            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();

            var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;

                // see https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resources.html
                options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
                options.UserInteraction = new UserInteractionOptions() { LoginUrl = "/Account/Login", LogoutUrl = "/Account/Logout" };
            })
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources)
                .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes)
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
                .AddProfileService<ProfileService>()
                .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();

            builder.AddSigningCredential(cert);
            // builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddGoogle("Google", options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;

                    options.ClientId = _clientId;
                    options.ClientSecret = _clientSecret;
                    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("picture", "picture", "url");
                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                })
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;

                    options.Authority = "https://accounts.google.com";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                    options.ResponseType = "code";
                    options.Scope.Add("profile");
                    options.Scope.Add("email");
                    options.Scope.Add("openid");

                    options.ClientId = _clientId;
                    options.ClientSecret = _clientSecret;
                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("picture", "picture", "url");
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        NameClaimType = "name",
                        RoleClaimType = "role",
                        ValidateIssuer = true
                    };
                });

                services.AddAuthorization();

                services.AddGrpc();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseGrpcWeb(new GrpcWebOptions { DefaultEnabled = true });
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapGrpcService<UserService>();
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute().RequireAuthorization();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**BackEnd/ProfileService.cs**

```
public class ProfileService : IProfileService
{
    public ProfileService()
    {
    }

    public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        var roleClaims = context.Subject.FindAll(JwtClaimTypes.Role);
        context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(roleClaims);

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

**FrontEnd/Program.cs**

```
namespace FrontEnd
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

            builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient()
                { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

            builder.Services.AddScoped(services => 
            {
                var httpHandler = new GrpcWebHandler(GrpcWebMode.GrpcWeb, new HttpClientHandler());
                var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5000", new GrpcChannelOptions
                    { 
                        HttpHandler = httpHandler
                    });

                return new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);
            });

            builder.Services.AddScoped(services => 
            {
                var baseAddressMessageHandler = services.GetRequiredService<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
                baseAddressMessageHandler.InnerHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
                var httpHandler = new GrpcWebHandler(GrpcWebMode.GrpcWeb, new HttpClientHandler());
                var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5000", new GrpcChannelOptions
                    { 
                        HttpHandler = httpHandler
                    });

                return new User.UserClient(channel);
            });
            
            builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
            {
                builder.Configuration.Bind("Authentication:Google", options.ProviderOptions);
                options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "SignedInUser";
            }).AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<CustomUserFactory>();

            builder.Services.AddOptions();
            
            builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();

        }
    }
```

**FrontEnd/wwwroot/appsettings.json**

```
{
    "Authentication":{
        "Google": {
            "Authority": "https://localhost:5000",
            "ClientId": <confidential>,
            "ClientSecret": "2fxc9srOe8QsRBnhzLIa1pF0",
            "DefaultScopes": [
                "email",
                "profile",
                "openid"
            ],
            "PostLogoutRedirectUri": "https://localhost:5001/",
            "RedirectUri": "https://localhost:5001/authentication/login-callback",
            "ResponseType": "code"
        },
}
```

This is the output from IdentityServer when i'm trying to sign-in

```
[18:34:28 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenValidator
Calling into custom token validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultCustomTokenValidator

[18:34:28 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.TokenValidator
Token validation success
{"ClientId": null, "ClientName": null, "ValidateLifetime": true, "AccessTokenType": "Jwt", "ExpectedScope": "openid", "TokenHandle": null, "JwtId": "8E6167D64F8FEA2FF6D12D17A1CEEBFE", "Claims": {"nbf": 1615548868, "exp": 1615552468, "iss": "https://localhost:5000", "aud": "https://localhost:5000/resources", "client_id": "499675830263-ldcg4fm7kcbjlt48tpaffqdbfnskmi8v.apps.googleusercontent.com", "sub": "81c306df-c1f0-4714-964f-2459b670429e", "auth_time": 1615548849, "idp": "oidc", "jti": "8E6167D64F8FEA2FF6D12D17A1CEEBFE", "sid": "0BF0BA4CA6BD3DE8D158A426A70A91E0", "iat": 1615548868, "scope": ["openid", "profile", "email", "role"], "amr": "external"}, "$type": "TokenValidationLog"}

[18:34:28 Debug] IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.UserInfoResponseGenerator
Creating userinfo response

[18:34:28 Debug] IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.UserInfoResponseGenerator
Scopes in access token: openid profile email role

[18:34:28 Debug] IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.UserInfoResponseGenerator
Requested claim types: sub name family_name given_name middle_name nickname preferred_username profile picture website gender birthdate zoneinfo locale updated_at email email_verified role

[18:34:28 Information] IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.UserInfoResponseGenerator
Profile service returned the following claim types: sub name preferred_username

[18:34:28 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.UserInfoEndpoint
End userinfo request

[18:34:29 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter
Request path /connect/checksession matched to endpoint type Checksession

[18:34:29 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter
Endpoint enabled: Checksession, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.CheckSessionEndpoint

[18:34:29 Information] IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware
Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.CheckSessionEndpoint for /connect/checksession

[18:34:29 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.CheckSessionEndpoint
Rendering check session result
```

From the output, the requested claims and the claims that's returned by the profile service is not matching

[image: What it looks like in the test page]
From the image, there should be a name after the "hello"

The image is similar except now it shows the name. IdentityServer4 is working fine, it shows everything as i expected

Comment: You ask " i only show the OpenID scope ", where? Consent screen?

Comment: no, but the claims is shown in the frontend and it only show the IDs neccessary but didn't show the profile and email info similar to the output identity server is showing . I'll update the post to include the image

Answer (score 0):

By default, only these claims are mapped from the ID-Token:

```
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("sub", "sub");
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("name", "name");
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("given_name", "given_name");
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("family_name", "family_name");
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("profile", "profile");
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("email", "email");
```

To get additional claims mapped, we have to write like:

```
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("website", "website");
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("gender", "gender");
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("birthdate", "birthdate");
```

In AddOpenIDConnect. This is called Claims transformation if you want to google for it.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail
about this topic: [Debugging OpenID Connect claim problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: I decided to create new identity server file and it worked perfectly. I think this is because before i started this side project, i didn't think it through about the backend security. So i think i'm going to start over for the backend.

Comment: a good practrice is to separate the client, API and IdentityServer in separate projects, makes the reasoning around the system much easier...

Comment: I still have the same problem event though i got the Identity Server to work but using oidc instead with google sign-in link as its authority, it still show the same like in the image, i'll update the post

Comment: So, what is the problem right now? I would l use a took like http://www.getfiddler.com to examine the tokens that the clients receive, to verify what they contain. because what you see in the token and in your application might now always be the same.

Comment: I got everything working for the identity server but the requested claims and the claims that is returned from the identity server to the client is not matching. I already updated the code

Comment: you need to do claims mapping if claims in the token does not end up in the User object. That is by design. only a few standard claims are included by default.